# Node_ Modules/qualifier/standalone. js 418:11

Tags: prettier, prettier-eslint, prettier-vscode, prettier-standard

I introduced Prettier in my React project, but there was a compilation error/ Node_ Modules/qualifier/standalone. js 418:11 I would like to know how to solve it,
When I commented out the code with the red border, there was no error in the code
but i dont konw how to fix it ,i wanna use the prettier~
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1GZbo.png)